# What happened to HasColumnName for EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

So I am trying to map an internal property to my database and according to this [article online](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166099/Entity-Framework-Storing-complex-properties-as-JSO) this is how you are supposed to do it. The other resources that I found also tell me to do the same thing. For whatever reason the method doesn't exist and I can't find online what they renamed it too or if they just removed the method.

Here is my code:

```
public class Criteria : DbEntity
{

    internal string _Condition { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Condition Condition 
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Condition) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Condition>(_Condition);
        }
        set
        {
            _Condition = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Criteria>().Property(b => b._Condition);//.HasColumnName("Condition"); <-- this doesn't exist...
}
```

Comment: Have you add the using directive `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` ?

Comment: I am already using it

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Can you build and post a small, complete repro.

Comment: Make sure you reference the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly.

Comment: Oh man.  I have this issue too, I am using Scaffold-DbContext and can't produce a valid context model.  Issues are there for .HasDefaultValueSql(), .HasColumnType(), .HasContstraintName().  I have tried through VS2017 and CLI.  I have tried using .Relational as @IvanStoev points out with no luck.  Not needed to do this for a while and a whole day has now gone trying different bits.

Comment: @ivanstoev That was it. Had no idea it was a separate nuget package.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Had to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` to fix the issue.

Edit:
Credit goes to [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) for finding this out

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server and using Core 3.1x, you can also fix this by installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.